# Is it possible to (re)connect hgsubversion to a manually constructed repository?

Tags: mercurial, hgsubversion

I am working with a repository whose root has moved around some in its history (started at trunk/, moved to subproject/trunk). Right now I can *either* use hgsubversion to work with all the history up to the point when it moved to subproject/trunk (see https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/issue/135/move-tracking), *or* I can use hg convert or rebase to splice together the histories into one cohesive repository.

After splicing and calling hg svn rebuildmeta, hgsubversion is all confused. New revisions in the svn repository are pulled into a branch called "../".

Basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to tell hgsubversion to use a certain svn revision as its reference point, only attempting to sync up the histories from that point forward?

Here is a small test illustrating the issue (sorry for the DOS commands)

```
C:\hgtest>svnadmin create svnrepo

C:\hgtest>svn co file:///C:/hgtest/svnrepo svncheckout
Checked out revision 0.

C:\hgtest>cd svncheckout

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>mkdir trunk/
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>svn mkdir trunk
A         trunk

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>cd trunk

C:\hgtest\svncheckout\trunk>echo "Test file version 1" > testfile.txt

C:\hgtest\svncheckout\trunk>cd ..

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>svn add trunk\testfile.txt
A         trunk\testfile.txt

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>svn ci -m "Original version in trunk configuration"
Adding         trunk
Adding         trunk\testfile.txt
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 1.

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>svn mkdir subproject
A         subproject

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>svn mv trunk subproject
A         subproject\trunk
D         trunk
D         trunk\testfile.txt

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>svn ci -m "Moved trunk to subproject/trunk"
Adding         subproject
Adding         subproject\trunk
Deleting       trunk

Committed revision 2.

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>echo ". Adding some text to distinguish the subproject/trunk version of this file" >> subproject\trunk\testfile.txt

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>svn ci -m "Final version of testfile.txt"
Sending        subproject\trunk\testfile.txt
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 3.

C:\hgtest\svncheckout>svn log subproject\trunk\testfile.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | kmahan | 2012-02-17 09:18:23 -0800 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012) | 1 line

Final version of testfile.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | kmahan | 2012-02-17 09:17:40 -0800 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012) | 1 line

Moved trunk to subproject/trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | kmahan | 2012-02-17 09:14:46 -0800 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012) | 1 line

Original version in trunk configuration
------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\hgtest>hg clone svn://localhost:22222/subproject/trunk hgrepo
[r2] kmahan: Moved trunk to subproject/trunk
[r3] kmahan: Final version of testfile.txt
pulled 2 revisions
updating to branch default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

C:\hgtest>cd hgrepo

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 74C7-4865

 Directory of C:\hgtest\hgrepo

02/17/2012  09:30 AM    <DIR>          .
02/17/2012  09:30 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/17/2012  09:30 AM    <DIR>          .hg
02/17/2012  09:30 AM               104 testfile.txt
               1 File(s)            104 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  1,705,932,423,168 bytes free

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg log --follow testfile.txt
changeset:   1:eae92a250a90
tag:         tip
user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
date:        Fri Feb 17 17:18:23 2012 +0000
summary:     Final version of testfile.txt

changeset:   0:10c6ad198001
user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
date:        Fri Feb 17 17:17:40 2012 +0000
summary:     Moved trunk to subproject/trunk


C:\hgtest>hg clone svn://localhost:22222/trunk -r 1 original-location
[r1] kmahan: Original version in trunk configuration
pulled 1 revisions
updating to branch default
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved


C:\hgtest>cd hgrepo

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg pull -f ..\original-location
pulling from ..\original-location
searching for changes
warning: repository is unrelated
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 0 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
(run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg log
changeset:   2:f968692b6301
tag:         tip
parent:      -1:000000000000
user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
date:        Fri Feb 17 17:14:46 2012 +0000
summary:     Original version in trunk configuration

changeset:   1:eae92a250a90
user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
date:        Fri Feb 17 17:18:23 2012 +0000
summary:     Final version of testfile.txt

changeset:   0:10c6ad198001
user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
date:        Fri Feb 17 17:17:40 2012 +0000
summary:     Moved trunk to subproject/trunk


C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg rebase -s 0 -d 2
saved backup bundle to C:\hgtest\hgrepo\.hg\strip-backup\10c6ad198001-backup.hg

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg log
changeset:   1:ee10af28394f
tag:         tip
user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
date:        Fri Feb 17 17:18:23 2012 +0000
summary:     Final version of testfile.txt

changeset:   0:f968692b6301
user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
date:        Fri Feb 17 17:14:46 2012 +0000
summary:     Original version in trunk configuration

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg svn rebuildmeta

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg pull
pulling from svn://localhost:22222/subproject/trunk
[r2] kmahan: Moved trunk to subproject/trunk
Marked branch ../ as closed.
[r3] kmahan: Final version of testfile.txt
no changes found

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>echo "Here's some more text" >> testfile.txt

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg ci -m "Test commit from mercurial side"

C:\hgtest\hgrepo>hg glog
o  changeset:   5:a0e38c8fcfaf
|  branch:      ../
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
|  date:        Fri Feb 17 17:43:38 2012 +0000
|  summary:     Added new text from the svn side
|
o  changeset:   4:39fe2d8d743c
|  branch:      ../
|  parent:      0:f968692b6301
|  user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
|  date:        Fri Feb 17 17:18:23 2012 +0000
|  summary:     Final version of testfile.txt
|
| o  changeset:   3:4a494fcf85f1
|/   branch:      ../
|    parent:      0:f968692b6301
|    user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
|    date:        Fri Feb 17 17:17:40 2012 +0000
|    summary:     Moved trunk to subproject/trunk
|
| @  changeset:   2:547ed469c516
| |  user:        Kyle Mahan <kmahan@redacted.com>
| |  date:        Fri Feb 17 09:33:07 2012 -0800
| |  summary:     Test commit from mercurial side
| |
| o  changeset:   1:ee10af28394f
|/   user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
|    date:        Fri Feb 17 17:18:23 2012 +0000
|    summary:     Final version of testfile.txt
|
o  changeset:   0:f968692b6301
   user:        kmahan@b3f284a4-0405-ad4c-b974-dac5aa90a095
   date:        Fri Feb 17 17:14:46 2012 +0000
   summary:     Original version in trunk configuration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it'll be a manual process. You'll need to find the high water mark revision for each branch and record it in the metadata files (the names of which escape me at the moment). At that point, things should mostly work.

Note: this is a theory. I have high confidence that it should work based on my memory of the code, but I've never tested it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion (and for writing the application!). When you say high water mark, does that mean the earliest point in time when they were in sync?

Comment: is there any chance to include support for these kinds of svn move ops . This is a very frequent situation in some contexts . In my case I have been maintaining an hg mirror of Apache™ Bloodhound initially pointing to the incubator area https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/bloodhound . [Project graduated](http://goo.gl/fb/7y1gC) recently so it is now at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/bloodhound . When pulling I get _abort: unable to work on a different path in the repository_ . This would happen with almost every new ASF project . What can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to tell hgsubversion to use a certain svn revision as its reference point, only attempting to sync up the histories from that point forward?

If I understood you correctly, you wanted --startrev option for clone command. From `hg help subversion`

> Sometimes, past repository history is of little or no interest, and
>   all one wants is to start from today and work forward. Using
>   "--startrev HEAD" causes the initial clone to only convert the latest
>   revision; later pulls will convert all subsequent revisions. Please
>   note that this only works for single-directory clones

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually have the opposite problem: I would like to have access to the full history in hg, but still be able to push new changesets up to the subversion repository. I was grasping at whether there might be some method to manually associate the svn and hg repository at some revision other than the root one.